# Re-format CSS classes to individual entries

Tags: css, notepad++, sublimetext3, adobe-brackets

With CSS we can list classes separated by comma like this:

```
ClassOne,
ClassTwo,
ClassTree {
    background: blue;
}
```

I need to re-format a stylesheet file so it becomes:

```
ClassOne {background: blue;}
ClassTwo {background: blue;}
ClassThree {background: blue;}
```

I am using Sublime Text 3 and I have thousands of lines of code, so I need some kind of batch operation to achieve this. I was hoping there was a package for Sublime Text that could do this, but I have not found any.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take http://www.codebeautifier.com/ , example http://take.ms/CetWI,
use this option http://take.ms/SkIKW